# How to rotate text in haskell so that only the individual words rotate not that whole text?

Tags: haskell, rotation

This text needs to rotate left with a natural number and rotate right when a negative number is entered.  So:

```
rotate 1    "foo bar baz" = "ofo rba zba"
rotate (-1) "foo bar baz" = "oof arb azb"
```

Also to add i can break down the text into lines and then words, i know all the lines, unlines, words, unwords. I'm having trouble with the definitions for moving the text left or right, do i need to use the head function?

Comment: Looks like a homework :) Start with splitting the text into words.

Comment: Hi, I've added an example to clarify what you mean (eg. not rotate as in an image).  If this wasn't what you meant, please correct me and clarify further.

Comment: Okay. A last tip. `cycle "bar"` gives `"barbarbarbar...`. This string contains any rotated versions of `bar`. Use `head` and `tail` to extract them. And no, there's no `head` involved in this code.

Answer (score 7):

To build the function you want, I provide you some bricks. Assembly instructions not included:

- The functions [words](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3awords) and [unwords](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aunwords) split a string into a list of its words and vice versa
- [cycle](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3acycle) creates an infinite list from its input by appending the list again and again
- [take](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3atake) takes a fixed amount of elements from a list
- [drop](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3adrop) drops a fixed amount of elements from a list
- [map](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3amap) applies a function to all elements of a list

(Documentation links found through [hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle))

Comment: [map](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:map) will also be useful for this I believe.